# Give any parameter to Vue.js via Blade (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, properties, vue.js, laravel-blade

Is there any way to pass a variable down from my php blade template to a Vue component (not a child) like this?

```
<component param="{{ $param }}"></component>
```

in vue.js component:

```
props: ['param']
```

I only get 'undefined'.

Thank you!

Comment: post your vue code too what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I just need to pass an ID to vue to use it for an axios get request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works just as I described. My problem was that I did not realise that HTML tags are not case sensitive. I had to correct

```
<component paramId="{{ $paramId }}"></component>
```

to

```
<component param-id="{{ $paramId }}"></component>
```

in order to access it via

```
props: ['tagId']
```